# Continuously listening to smart contract events

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, nft, etherscan

My NFT project architecture in such way that only when a minting event has occurred, a `minted` event is emitted and then I want to listen to that event so I trigger an upload of the JSON content that would be then visible to token owner (since anyone can potentially access the content of all the token by basically going to `baseURI/tokenID` and I want to keep the rarity of the tokens a secret until minted).

I want to create a function that continuously listens to new events from the `minted` event. I'm trying to access new events by using the following implementation, because I couldn't find an implementation that continuously listens to events from the contract.

```
async function listener() {
    events = nftContract.getPastEvents("minted",{fromBlock: 1}, function(err,res) {
        console.log(res);
    })
```

What is the best way to create a function that continues to poll events from the contract?

Comment: I refer you to my answer here: [Getting all newly minted ERC721 contracts with an ethereum node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919064/getting-all-newly-minted-erc721-contracts-with-an-ethereum-node/68963641#68963641)

Answer (score 0):

The full code of the solution is so:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x10820dB......";
const ABIJSON = JSON.parse('{"_format": "hh-sol-artifact-1", "contractName": "testcontract", "....}')
provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider("ropsten");
const contract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABIJSON.abi, provider);

contract.on("eventName", ( caller,tokenID) => {
      //this section is called every time an event is emitted 
})
```