# How to filter an event by its parameters

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to subscribe to an event, but also filter by its parameter. In other words, I want to only receive events that matches a specified value within `id`.

```
event PaymentMade(string id);

function pay(string id) public payable {
    // process payment
    
    emit PaymentMade(id);
}

// i.e. only receive the event if id == "something"
```

When I try [web3.eth.subscribe](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html#web3-eth-subscribe), I'm able to get the event from a specific address and the specified topics only:

```js
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x123456..',
    topics: ['0x12345...']
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});
```

But the problem is, I'm getting the all instances of the `PaymentMade` event regardless of what the parameter `id` is. I'm also unsure how to pass the parameter value to filter by.

If I use [getPastEvents](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=getPastEvents#getpastevents), I'm able to specify the filter value, but I"m still getting all events regardless of the parameter:

```js
let options = {
    filter: {
        value: [id]    //Only get events where the id matches a certain value
    },
    fromBlock: 0,              
    toBlock: 'latest'
};


try {
    const result = await contract.getPastEvents('paymentMade', options)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Finally, I've tried with and without `indexed` parameter for the `PaymentMade` event, but none seem to work.

Comment: I know some ways in ethers.js, if you did not find any useful answers, use ethers.js for this part of your dapp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919064/getting-all-newly-minted-erc721-contracts-with-an-ethereum-node/68963641#68963641